# What guidelines specify that WHEEL_DELTA = 120 for a single mouse wheel click?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I’ve listened to a couple of ‘wheel’ events on the body element of my web page, and I noticed that the events all had wheelDelta property values of 120 (for single up ticks of the mouse wheel) or -120 (for single down ticks of the mouse wheel).

What standard out there says that the value of wheelDelta has to be 120/-120 for full mouse tick?

Microsoft Developer network notes this in the documentation for a Mousewheel event, but there has to be some broader standard out there. Does W3C specify that a single mouse tick is 120/-120?

Comment: And if you're curious why 120 is such a common value: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/23/10387366.aspx

Comment: the W3C does not spec those wheel events, only the newer wheel events that don't even have a wheelDelta property: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-wheel see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel#Specification for details